# Why did the Particle Accelerator in Earth-2 explode when it did?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the first season we learn that Eobard Thawne - posing as Dr. Harrison Welles - deliberately caused the particle accelerator to go boom to "make" Barry the Flash. We also learned he changed history by doing so, as it would have gone off by accident in 2024 had he not changed anything.

Thing is, in Earth-2, Thawne never went back to the past (AFAWK), never killed Welles and stole his identity - so shouldn't the explosion occur nine years from now?

Comment: Earth-2 is shown to be quite a bit more technologically advanced than E-1, so it's not unreasonable to summarize that Welles-2 was able to complete the particle accelerator almost a decade earlier than Welles-1 would have.

Comment: yeah what chahk said is the impression i got, they are a few years ahead in some areas over on earth 2 which would allow for the time gap

Comment: Isn't his name spelled Wells? I was believing it was an hommage to H.G. Wells...

Comment: @Taladris- Maybe, but if we're going to call out spelling errors it's homage :).